# junit - mockito - exception

Tags: exception, junit, mockito

I'm new to JUnit. I have to test a method in which a method call has to throw an exception and it enters into catch block. I need to test this flow using JUnit. When I try `Mockito.when(method).thenThrow()` it is not throwing the exception and flow is not going into catch block.

My class to be tested:

```
public String exceptionMethod() {
  String return = null;
  ClassOne one = new ClassOne();
  try {
    //code
    one.methodname(parameters); // this is a method which has to throw exception
    return = happy path ;
    //code
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    return = exception ;
    //code
  }
}
```

JUnit class:

```
@Mock
Classone one = new Classone();

@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void testExceptionMethod(){
  Mockito.when(one.method).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
  //code
  String msg = exceptionMethod();
  assertEquals(msg,"exception");
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the code as a code block, properly indented.

Comment: this code is a mess, and won't compile, there's no Public keyword in the first place. Many other problems occur later.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close! You need to check a few things:

1. Make sure that you're calling [`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)) in a `@Before` method, or that you're using [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) or a [`MockitoRule`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html). This gives Mockito the chance to initialize your `@Mock` fields.
2. Ensure that your class and method are eligible for mocking: Neither can be final or static. Make sure you check the [Mockito limitations FAQ entry](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito).
3. Calling `new ClassOne()` is the big problem, because it establishes that you're not using the mock ClassOne that you create in your test. You'll need to figure out a way to ensure that your mock is installed in your system under test. Some ideas:

   - Create a *method override for testing* that takes in a ClassOne, that you call from your test.
   - Create a *factory method* on your system under test that calls `new ClassOne()` but can be overridden in your test to return the mock.
   - Create your ClassOne up front and save it into a field, then in your test replace that field with your mock.